# Create new variables in multiple data

Tags: r, loops, variables, for-loop

I have a dataset with 30 Data and I had written a loop to read all of them into the enviroment. (Thats works good).

All of them have the same 6 variables and I want to write a loop, to get a new variable in all of them. This Variable should consist of a substraction of two other Variables. Both are numeric. So thats my code.

```
list <- c("Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4")

for (i in list){

i[,7] <- i[,5] - i[,2] 

}

Get this:
Error in i[, 5] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

R can't indentify the `i` as the variable in list. But I don't know why, because in the loop before (to read all the Datas to the Enviroment) it works perfect! I also try to write `i$Variable7 <- i$Variable5 - i$Variable2` but doesnt work, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the datasets in a `list`, loop through the `list` with `lapply`, update the 7th column with the difference of 5th and 2nd columns

```
lst <- lapply(mget(list), function(x) {x[,7] <- x[,5] - x[,2]; x})
```

If we really wanted to update the original dataset objects,

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

---

The reason why the OP's code didn't work was because it was looping through the string and not getting the values of the dataset object